# How do I force Windows 10 notification duration to be less than 5 seconds?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications

If you go into settings > Ease of Access in Windows 10, you can adjust the duration of time for which notifications appear in the bottom left hand corner of your screen. The minimum duration there is 5 seconds.

If you go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility in the registry editor, you can manually adjust the "MessageDuration" entry to be whatever you like. ***However***, as far as I can tell (and from what I've seen in articles online), Windows 10 will continue to show notifications for 5 seconds if that entry is set to anything less than 5. It works fine if you choose any number of seconds above 5.

My question is, how can I get Windows 10 to acknowledge my desire to have a notification duration of 2 or 3 seconds? It's maddening that the Windows 10 devs think they know better than someone who is capable of registry edits (Not that that's a challenging task, but that it shows I'm not an inept computer user).

Comment: Any luck finding the answer yet? this is driving me insane when I am trying to work. If I touch the volume control that screen becomes useless for 5 seconds and I have to break my concentration when carefully moving my mouse to another monitor incase I pass the giant notification and start the time again!

Comment: @Hicsy No luck yet, I gave up. Hoping one day a hero will swoop in with an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to tinker (at your own risk...) in \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\ATs\messageduration ?

Comment: @Didier Sorry for the late reply; I do not have "Accessibility" as an option at the path you described. Seemed like a good guess though.

Comment: I found this \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility but when you set something less than 5, it remains 5 second. This only work for numbers more than 5

Comment: It looks like its "by design" ... [see here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/notification-length-less-than-5-seconds/c147317f-08c1-494f-9e50-7e80e5756e48)

Comment: Even better would be if it'd be possible to specify it app dependent (or even more customizable, that'd be true user experience in that regard) because some stuff I want to see longer than other, but still not for longer). And btw @1NN that may be, but it's another example of stupid windows design because that mean's there's some other variable somewhere that's making this sure, which completely defeats the seaming point of the registry. I mean if you do this for important stuff, sure, but for a #u#king notification, that's just hilarious (actually not obviously). Well whatever, 5 sec it is

Comment: Only thing you can do on newer windows versions is to remove the visual notification entirely.

Answer (score 1):

*I was also trying to do this and found this thread.*

Unfortunately, **`bcdedit /timeout 3` does not work, it is for editing the bootmenu timeout and has nothing to do with notifications**, as stated here by microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--timeout.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that needs **"zero seconds"** (= never show notifications):

Open settings, search for "focus assist". Choose: "alarms only". No more annoying notifications! You can also set some automatic rules for turning on or off the notifications.

[image: Focus Assist]

While the focus assist is on, you can still click on the far end of the task bar, and any "missed out" notifications will show up as a list.

[image: far end of taskbar]